# Error installing apache2.2-common

Tags: apache2, software-installation

I'm having an inssue installing apache2.2-common.  The actual issue is installing libapache2-mod-mono, but that errors with the apache2.2-common dependency.

Here's the error message. Any idea what I can do to get this installed?  I'm running Linux Mint 13.

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2.2-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: apache2-data (= 2.4.6-2~precise+1) but it is not going to be installed
           Conflicts: apache2.2-common but 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4 is to be installed
 apache2-bin : Conflicts: apache2.2-common but 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4 is to be installed
 apache2.2-common : Depends: apache2.2-bin (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) but 2.4.6-2~precise+1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

---

UPDATE:

A little more info: I uninstalled a bunch of stuff and started from scratch.  Now when I try to install apache2.2-common I get just one error:

```
The following packages have unmet depenecies:
apache2.2-common : Depends: apache2.2-bin (=2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) but it is not going to be installed.
E: Unable to correct problems you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: see message for an update

Comment: I get the same error trying to install libapache2-mod-perl2

Comment: Are you running an Apache PPA or something?  It looks like your conflict is because the binaries and the apache2-data files are different from the actual common files.

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding the `is not going to be installed` packages to the main installation list:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common
```